# Problem with theme after upgrading Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10

Tags: themes, gtk4

After upgrading Ubuntu 22.04 to 22.10 the dark theme stopped working for GTK4 apps. Nautilus, settings etc. have default light theme no matter what I change.

- When i change dark/light theme in settings>appearance, older apps change appearance but not the new ones

What I tried:

- Changing theme with gnome tweaks same behavior
- I did restart X11 session after changes and it did not solve the problem.
- I tried to reinstall user themes extension
- I tried to reinstall gnome tweaks

I will provide you with any logs but i have no idea how to debug broken gtk4 theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue, because I used a custom theme in Ubuntu 22.04. To solve the issue for Nautilus I just removed the folder `~/.config/gtk-4.0`

But I still have theming issues with the Gnome Shell (top panel).

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my issue! Shell theme also doesn't change for me, but i am able to change it through tweaks.

Comment: I could solve my Gnome Shell issue by reinstalling the Yaru theme.

Comment: Delete the folder ~/.config/gtk-4.0, did not work? The theme does not change, its still Nautilus default theme.